# Error Psycopg2 Mac OS X Mountain Lion Symbol not found: _GSS_C_NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE

Tags: django, postgresql, osx-mountain-lion, psycopg2

I'm getting a psycopg2 error after updating to Mac OS X Mountain Lion, previously it was working fine. 
This is the error if I try to import the module:

```
    Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 27 2012, 21:57:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.65))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Symbol not found: _GSS_C_NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
```

I've used brew to install python and psycopg2.
Any idea would be helpful.

Thanks 
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Try brewing postgresql too. The error is probably in the way the libpq (the PostgreSQL client-side library, of which psycopg is a wrapper) is linked.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I can't use Brew to install PostgreSQL because the version is not compatible with Django. :(

Answer (score 0):

Mixing native and brew app is not that good... I would rather uninstall psycopg2 and python from brew and install the "Command Line Tools", like explained in [pip install fails with /usr/bin/clang: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791806/10-8-first-attempts-pip-install-psycopg2-fails-usr-bin-clang-no-such-file-o?rq=1). Then retry pip install, it will work, at least it did the job for me !