# Error when installing Cython for use with Buildozer

Tags: macos, clang, pip, cython, kivy

I've run into an error while installing Kivy, which told me to install Cython, so I did.
Except I run into an error, I've tried installing with pip,easy_install, manually but it results in the same. I also tried installing a older version of Cython but no luck.

Error message:
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/Cython/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-nXMqSR-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --**compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/Cython**
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/jorn/Library/Logs/pip.log

When I install manually I get this error:
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c Cython/Plex/Scanners.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/Cython/Plex/Scanners.o
unable to execute clang: No such file or directory
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

I have read and tried all solutions I could find but none work..

I'm running on Mac osx 10.8.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [pip install fails with /usr/bin/clang: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791806/pip-install-fails-with-usr-bin-clang-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: yes, i've seen it and already tried that option but no luck

Comment: Alright. I've retagged your question to get you better help - this doesn't seem to be a cython or Kivy problem but an OSX/clang problem.

Comment: @RyanP , thanks! I just found out the solution to the problem by your last comment :D, I will post it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to what @RaynP just said about it being a osx/clang issue I found the solution:
credits to this blog: http://kaspermunck.github.io/2014/03/fixing-clang-error/
The error is related to Xcode 5.1.

You will have to download the cython-master from GitHub. Installing with pip will not work and results in another error.

in terminal go to the cython-master file and enter: sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future python setup.py install

This is a workaround the error.
Now I have installed Cython and can finally compile my app with Kivy/Buildozer:D

Comment: well, this error is fixed, on to the next one..lol:
error: command 'arm-linux-androideabi-gcc' failed with exit status 1
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "kivytutorial"